# Sharepoint 2010 - how do I modify a taxonomic property?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to modify a taxonomic user profile property in Sharepoint 2010. Just as an example, let's say I wanted to modify the Interests property (aka SPS-Interests, or PropertyConstants.Interests). I tried setting the property value with the semicolon-delimited string, like this:

```
var property = profile[PropertyConstants.Interests];
if (property != null)
{
    property.Value = "sharepoint; stackoverflow; scotch";                    
}
```

But that throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for SharePoint 2010, but in 2007, profile[propertyName] is a UserProfileValueCollection, so it can contain multiple values.

This may work:

```
profile[PropertyConstants.Interests].Clear();
profile[PropertyConstants.Interests].Add("sharepoint");
profile[PropertyConstants.Interests].Add("stackoverflow");
profile[PropertyConstants.Interests].Add("scotch");
```

In 2007, you also need to call the Commit method on the userprofile to save the changes to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether it is relevant anymore but here is a quick and dirty approach:

```
property.Value = new string[] {"sharepoint; stackoverflow; scotch"};
```

Works like a charm! Cleans out previous value and replaces with your string array.

Although there are limitations/advantages:
This way it doesn't omit duplicates. If you would consequently use Add method for "Value1", "Value2", "Value1". The result of saving would be "Value1;Value2".
With the new string[] approach it would save all three of them (I really needed that behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

```
    internal void updateUserProfileExperienceTags(string psLabelGuidValuePairs, string psDomainUser)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Security.PermissionSet ps = new System.Security.PermissionSet
            (
                System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted
            );
            ps.Assert();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
                UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                ProfileSubtypePropertyManager pspm = upm.DefaultProfileSubtypeProperties;
                UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(psDomainUser);
                TaxonomyFieldValueCollection _TaxonomyFieldValueCollection = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(String.Empty);
                _TaxonomyFieldValueCollection.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(psLabelGuidValuePairs);
                TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(SPContext.Current.Site);
                TermStore termStore = session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
                TermSetCollection termSets = termStore.GetTermSets("Technology", 1033);
                TermSet sTerms = termSets[0];
                profile["Skills-Experience"].Clear();
                for (int ni = 0; ni < _TaxonomyFieldValueCollection.Count; ni++)
                {
                    Guid guid = new Guid(_TaxonomyFieldValueCollection[ni].TermGuid);
                    Term sTerm = sTerms.GetTerm(guid);
                    profile["Skills-Experience"].AddTaxonomyTerm(sTerm);
                }
                profile.Commit();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "updateUserProfileExperienceTags: " + ex.ToString() });
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
        }
    }
```

This works fine for me. Be sure the user has 'Allow users to edit values for this property' enabled >in CA -> User Profile Service -> User Profile Property -> Edit Settings

Comment: When I reach to the line `profile["Skills-Experience"].AddTaxonomyTerm(sTerm);` in my code I am getting an error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.` My property is single value. What should I do?

Comment: First you set the property value using statement as per my code:  `profile["Skills-Experience"].Value = sTerm.Label;` Then place the statement right below `profile["Skills-Experience"].AddTaxonomyTerm(sTerm);`. Let me know if it works or not. @IDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer to your question, but as I was looking for something similar and found out how to do that, I thought it might be interesting for other people as well:

The UserProfileValueCollection class has various new Taxonomy-specific methods in SharePoint 2010 that are worth looking into:

- AddTaxonomyTerm
- GetTaxonomyTerms
- RemoveTaxonomyTerm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilevaluecollection_methods.aspx

I guess this is the "proper" way to access Taxonomy-based user profile properties.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
userprofile["propertyname"].Add(" ");

userprofile["propertyname"].AddTaxonomyTerm(taxonomyterm);

userprofile.Commit();
```